# Save mapView as image without rendering it on screen

Tags: android, osmdroid

I'm creating free activity monitoring app similar to Strava. Using vtm-android as map library.

I would like save org.oscim.android.MapView as image, without rendering it to screen.

I found several solutions, how to save view as image, but unfortunately none of them is working when when view is not "attached" to existing component tree.

My expectation was to initialize MapView like this:

```
final String MAP_FILE = "somemap.map";
MapView mapView = new MapView(mContext);

final org.oscim.map.Map map = mapView.map();
MapFileTileSource tileSource = new MapFileTileSource();

String mapPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), MAP_FILE).getAbsolutePath();
if (tileSource.setMapFile(mapPath)) {
    // Vector layer
    VectorTileLayer tileLayer = map.setBaseMap(tileSource);

    // Render theme
    map.setTheme(VtmThemes.DEFAULT);

    double latitude = 49.1625214;
    double longitude = 20.2644075;

    // Note: this map position is specific to Berlin area
    map.setMapPosition(latitude, longitude, 1 << 12);
}

mapView.layout(0, 0, 200, 200);

//Get the dimensions of the view so we can re-layout the view at its current size
//and create a bitmap of the same size
int width = view.getWidth();
int height = view.getHeight();

int measuredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
int measuredHeight = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

//Cause the view to re-layout
view.measure(measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());

//Create a bitmap backed Canvas to draw the view into
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

//Now that the view is laid out and we have a canvas, ask the view to draw itself into the canvas
view.draw(canvas);

ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bitmap.getByteCount());
bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer);

//save bytes from bytebuffer to file or db
```

But instead of map image, I get full transparent image.

Comment: Try to use this PixelShot library: https://github.com/Muddz/PixelShot

Answer (score 0):

To take screen shot you need render it on screen. Without rendering screenshot is not possible

Answer (score 0):

mapView.getDrawingCache()

> It will return you bitmap of current displaying.

Bitmap capturedScreen = Bitmap.createBitmap(mapView.getDrawingCache()); imageView.setImageBitmap(capturedScreen);

Here 'capturedScreen' will give you image of mapview.